# How Do I Redirect an Ajax PHP String to a new URL with Native Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, redirect

If my php string is like this. $ResponseG is my string.

```
$responseG = $_SESSION['id']." | ";
$responseG .= $_SESSION['type']." | ";
$responseG .= $_SESSION['username']." | ";
$responseG .= $_SESSION['last_active']." | ";
$responseG .= $_SESSION['last_login']." | ";
```

Which would be something like this.

2 | user | username | time1 | time2

Here is the Ajax

```
if(RequestObject){
RequestObject.open("POST", "calls/checkLog.php");
RequestObject.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
RequestObject.onreadystatechange = function(){
if(RequestObject.readyState == 4 && RequestObject.status == 200){
if(RequestObject.readyState == 4){
if(RequestObject.responseText !== "Username or Password are Invalid!"){
if(RequestObject.responseText !== "Username and Password are Required to Continue."){
window.location.replace("http://folder/members.php");
}else{document.getElementById('alertLog').innerHTML = RequestObject.responseText;}
}else{document.getElementById('alertLog').innerHTML = RequestObject.responseText;}}}}
var dataStringA = document.getElementById('inputaID').value;
var dataStringB = document.getElementById('password').value;
var data = dataStringA+'|'+dataStringB+'|';
RequestObject.send("data=" + data);}
return false;}
```

In this section i was wanting to sent the string to the redirected URL
How do i send the php string to the members.php page

```
window.location.replace("http://folder/members.php");
```

Please no jQuery. The solution must be in native Javascript.  Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `window.location.replace('<?php echo $url; ?>');`

Comment: The url is fine when redirecting i want to send the php string of data with the url redirect.  The Redirected Url does a check for the data in the string.

Comment: i would like to send the data to the new url

Comment: `window.location.replace('http://folder/members.php?data='+data);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by passing the response in the query string of the URL:

```
window.location.replace("http://folder/members.php?userInfo=" + encodeURIComponent(RequestObject.responseText));
```

You should then be able to access the passed data in members.php using `$_GET['userInfo']`